# Can I email someone (with) something?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I say "I emailed you (with) a brief introduction of our program along with the application link"?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you intend with the parenthetical. Is it a literal part of the text you’re asking about. Does it express an either/or that you are asking us about? Something else?

Comment: This seems a lot like a proofreading request, which would be off-topic on this site. Please indicate why you think that "with" might or might not be allowed. (Basically, tell us the results of the research that you did.)

Comment: Since when did we start mailing people with things? Usually we just mail people things and that's the end of it. I guess you could mail someone with a big enough box for them to be comfortable in for the journey.

Comment: I have heard this usage ("email with") before; I think it's at least somewhat common.

Comment: I suppose you might use "with" to refer to an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are acceptable. When we use the preposition "[with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)" in the context of emailing someone, it is meant in the sense of "having or including".  So if you say

> I emailed you a picture of my dog

then you are indicating that the picture of your dog was the entire reason for your email. The email was the means by which you sent the picture of your dog.

If you say

> I emailed you with a picture of my dog

then the picture of your dog might be a secondary concern. Perhaps you were emailing your friend with a letter of correspondence, and the picture was an added bonus.

So, if we take your original message, if the main point of the email was to send "a brief introduction of our program", then it would be better to have that as the direct object of "email", (without "with") especially since you are sending it "along with the application link", which sounds like the extra feature of the email.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).